# Routing HTTP Error 404.0 0x80070002

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, routes, url-routing

I have created routing rules in my ASP.NET application and on my Dev machine at IIS7 everything works fine. When I deploy solution to prod server which has also IIS7 I get error 404 (page not found) while accessing URL. Maybe someone could point where is the problem?

Actual error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The
>   resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable. Detailed
>   Error InformationModule IIS Web Core 
>   Notification MapRequestHandler 
>   Handler StaticFile  Error Code
>   0x80070002  Requested URL
>   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/pdf-button 
>   Physical Path
>   C:\www\pathtoproject\pdf-button  Logon
>   Method Anonymous  Logon User Anonymous

My Actual Code

```
     <add key="RoutePages" value="all,-forum/"/>

             UrlRewrite.Init(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RoutePages"]);


    public static class UrlRewrite
    {
            public static void Init(string routePages)
            {

                _routePages = routePages.ToLower().Split(new[] { ',' });
                RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes);




            }

            static void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
            {

                routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                routes.Ignore("favicon.ico");
                foreach (string routePages in _routePages)
                {
                    if (routePages == "all")
                        routes.MapPageRoute(routePages, "{filename}", "~/{filename}.aspx");
                    else
                        if (routePages.StartsWith("-"))
                            routes.Ignore(routePages.Replace("-", ""));
                        else
                        {
                            var routePagesNoExt = routePages.Replace(".aspx", "");
                            routes.MapPageRoute(routePagesNoExt, routePagesNoExt, string.Format("~/{0}.aspx", routePagesNoExt));
                        }
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: what type of routing you used ? MVC ?

Comment: I use System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection class (.NET 4.0)

Comment: What are you expecting it to be routed to - pdf-button.aspx? As I'm sure you've realised 0x80070002 = ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 28):

Just found that lines below must be added to `web.config` file, now everything works fine on production server too.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  alone has done the job but solution given by Robert Bethge is also better.

Answer (score 13):

The solution suggested

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

works, but can degrade performance and can even cause errors, because now all registered HTTP modules run on every request, not just managed requests (e.g. .aspx). This means modules will run on every .jpg .gif .css .html .pdf etc.

A more sensible solution is to include this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Credit for his goes to Colin Farr. Check-out his post about this topic at http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html.

Answer (score 4):

My solution, after trying EVERYTHING:

Bad deployment, an old **PrecompiledApp.config** was hanging around my deploy location, and making everything not work.

My final settings that worked:

- IIS 7.5, Win2k8r2 x64,
- Integrated mode application pool
- *Nothing changes in the web.config* - this means no special handlers for routing. Here's my snapshot of the sections a lot of other posts reference. I'm using FluorineFX, so I do have that handler added, but I did not need any others:

  ```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="None"/>

    <pages validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <!-- Modules for IIS 7.0 Integrated mode -->
      <modules>
        <add name="FluorineGateway" type="FluorineFx.FluorineGateway, FluorineFx" />
      </modules>

      <!-- Disable detection of IIS 6.0 / Classic mode ASP.NET configuration -->
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
  ```
- Global.ashx: (only method of any note)

  ```
  void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      // Register routes...
      System.Web.Routing.Route echoRoute = new System.Web.Routing.Route(
            "{*message}",
          //the default value for the message
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", "" } },
          //any regular expression restrictions (i.e. @"[^\d].{4,}" means "does not start with number, at least 4 chars
            new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary() { { "message", @"[^\d].{4,}" } },
            new TestRoute.Handlers.PassthroughRouteHandler()
         );

      System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(echoRoute);
  }
  ```
- PassthroughRouteHandler.cs - this achieved an automatic conversion from http://andrew.arace.info/stackoverflow to http://andrew.arace.info/#stackoverflow which would then be handled by the default.aspx:

  ```
  public class PassthroughRouteHandler : IRouteHandler {

      public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) {
          HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["message"];
          requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("#" + HttpContext.Current.Items["IncomingMessage"], true);
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: You saved my day with PrecompiledApp.config info. :-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: 10 years later, and I just got bitten by an old PrecompiledApp.config. Wow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was a new server that System.Web.Routing was of version 3.5 while web.config requested version 4.0.0.0.
The resolution was

%WINDIR%\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

%WINDIR%\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

Answer (score 0):

Having this in Global.asax.cs solved it for me.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck this in Windows Explorer.

"Hide file type extensions for known types"