# How to Publish DotNet Core (v5.0) Web Api to IIS?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

First thing I did was install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS server;
I have also stopped and re-started IIS;

I've tested and can confirm my app runs on Krestel, but I am struggling to get it running (in-proc) in IIS;

**Running with Krestel (good/pass):**

1. On my local PC, "Publish" as Framework-dependent to MyAppFolder
   (this folder now contains all the compiled assets for my app, including exec and dll's)
2. Move MyAppFolder somewhere on the IIS server;
3. Run the executable (MyWebApi.exe) directly on the cmd line , I get the default
   Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

If I navigate to an end point with a Browser,
http://localhost:5000/MyResource/123
, this GET request produces the desired json result;

**Running with IIS (bad/fail):**

1. As stated above, NET Core Hosting Bundle is installed, including stop/start the iis server
2. Created an App Pool (No Managed Code)
3. Created a Virtual App on the IIS Manager (MyVirtualApp), which points to the folder containing all the assets for my app (same folder that works with Krestel)

That should be it, I think, but it doesn't work ? Did I miss any steps ?
When I point a Browser to my resource
http://localhost/MyVirtualApp/MyResource/123
, I get a **404**!

**Additional Info:**

```
//Program.cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Docs say I don't need to explicitly `UseIIS`, as CreateDefaultBuilder will use IIS or Krestel;

Also, dotnet --info gives the below:

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.17
  Commit:  6a98414363

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**The 404 Error page:** (as given by IIS)

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module:         IIS Web Core
Notification:   MapRequestHandler
Handler:        StaticFile
Error Code: 0x80070002
```

This IIS error appears to be related to routing, [Routing HTTP Error 404.0 0x80070002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677099/routing-http-error-404-0-0x80070002)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the "target folder" produced by the "Publish" wizard in Visual Studio produces a parent folder containing my app's exe and dll's, plus children subfolders called **publish**, **ref**, **runtimes**;

In IIS I configured my site's physical path to be at the parent folder level, when it should have been to the **publish** folder ! (I see no reason for the team at MS to generate files at the parent folder, and again inside the publish folder - why double up and make it confusing !).

Comment: The documentation on `-o` clearly states what is the default target folder, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish#options "If not specified, it defaults to [project_file_folder]/bin/[configuration]/[framework]/publish/ for a framework-dependent executable and cross-platform binaries. It defaults to [project_file_folder]/bin/[configuration]/[framework]/[runtime]/publish/ for a self-contained executable." So if you feel "confusing", you should spend more time reading the whole thing.

Comment: @Lex Li Ok, but I did not use the cmd line to publish, hence there was no reason for me to dig into the docs above;  As I said, I used the VS studio wizard, where I choose a Target folder; Still they put all files into the target folder, and AGAIN into the publish folder. So you have not given a reason why they need to waste diskspace but generating it twice.

Comment: "As I said, I used the VS studio wizard, where I choose a Target folder; Still they put all files into the target folder, and AGAIN into the publish folder." No, that's not the case. The target folder you chose in VS publish wizard is strictly the destination VS/.NET Core tooling generates the final output for deployment (equivalent to `-o`). You might set something in VS and later in IIS Manager pick up a wrong location (like its parent folder), but it is unreasonable to blame that's "confusing".

Comment: @Lex Li, Ok you are right, my bad.. the Wizard sets a default target location as "bin\Release\net5.0\publish\" So I am seen it 2x because assets are published for the Release folder, and again for the Publish folder; So If I set the target folder to be outside the Release folder, I would have seen it once only.